# Camel route trigger sequence using rest and MQ

Tags: java, rest, apache-camel, ibm-mq, spring-bean

I have exposesd a rest endpoint and want to do processing of incomming request as below steps:

> 1. Get the message from rest call
> 2. validate the message (`restRequestValidationProcessor`)
> 3. sent acknowledgement response to caller app (rest call initiator using `bean:restCallResponserService`)
> 4. send the original msg to mq for processing (`ref:mqueueEndpoint`)
> 5. As soon as msg comes in mq, another route triggers for msg processing.

Currently trying in below way:

```
<restConfiguration component="servlet" bindingMode="off">
<rest path="/">
 <post uri="/messages" >
 <to uri="direct:handleRestCall" />
 </post>
</rest>

<route>
<from uri="direct:handleRestCall" />
  <process ref="restRequestValidationProcessor" />
    <to uri="ref:mqueueEndpoint" />
    <to uri="bean:restCallResponserService?method=generateSuccessResponse"/>
    <onException>
    <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
     <handled>
     <constant>true</constant>
     </handled>
      <process ref="exceptionProcessor"></process>
    </onException>
</route>

<route>
 <from uri="ref:csQueueEndpoint" />
  <process ref="msgProcessor"></process>
</route>
```

Problem is - some time it seams that client app (soap ui) is waiting for longer than needed.  I want client not wait for actual msg processing but it looks message has started processing and client has not got acknowledgement. In my opinion, since MQ processing is asynchronous, before queue processing route (2nd route in below snippet), `restCallResponser (<to uri="bean:restCallResponserService?method=generateSuccessResponse"/>)` should trigger and client will get the response and in background queue route would be executing .. which is not happening using below conf.

Can someone suggest how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

As routes are also running in parallel it is not possible to ensure that client will have response before message processing started or completed.

generateSuccessResponse needs to be investigated for late response. Log the times on start and end in the method and see where is the delay in there.

Comment: generateSuccessResponse  doesnot have any thing except than one String " message received" for acknowledgement and that getting set in exchange body.

Comment: Various ways to implement. Depends on your application. The simplest is to put delay into first lines of `code`<process ref="msgProcessor"></process>`code`. If it is not acceptable think about synchronization between those two routes. You may define a synchronized map and put messages into there in the end of first route. In the second route started process takes incoming message and looks for that in map. If not found, waits a little bit and tries again and again till found and processes. Then removes message from the map.